# Change background color of a WPF ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have to change Background color of an ItemTemplate of a ListBox, depending the value of a boolean. 
Here is my ListBox :

```
<ListBox Name="itemListBox" 
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
         SelectionChanged="itemListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Width="200">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="{Binding Path=Value.DocID}" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Text="{Binding Path=Value.Serial}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If the user delete an Item, I want to show him in grey backrgound.
Precision : The ListBox is binded to a Dictionnary, that contains a boolean value "IsDeleted".
Sorry for the poor English.
Thank you

Comment: "If the user delete an Item", what does that mean in your code? Does the item have a flag that indicates that it has been deleted?

Comment: The ListBox is binded to a Dictionnary, that contains a boolean value "IsDeleted"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an `ItemContainerStyle` with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<ListBox Name="itemListBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="itemListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value.IsDeleted}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Width="200">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Value.DocID}" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Value.Serial}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Make sure that the class with the `IsDeleted` property implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface correctly if you intend to set the property dynamically and want the background to get updated accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much !  
Yes, INotifyPropertyChanged was implemented.